# Inno Setup: How to check if JRE is present and prompt to download if not?

Tags: java, installation, virtual-machine, inno-setup, setup-project

I'm developing the installer for a Java 64 bit application with Inno Setup.

It is possible with Inno Setup to check if Java 64 bit is present in the computer and if not to display the user a link for download Java 64 bit?

What should I add to Inno Setup script it to achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find a script that could check if JRE is installed then prompt a message for the user I used this Stack Overflow post as reference: [How do I install a JRE from an Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24964393)

```pascal
[Code]
{ Script to check if a JRE is installed }

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  JavaVer: string;
begin
    RegQueryStringValue(
        HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 'CurrentVersion', JavaVer);
    Result := (Length(JavaVer) > 0);
    if not Result then
    begin
        if MsgBox('YOUR MESSAGE GOES HERE', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = idYes then
        begin
            ShellExec(
              'open', 'https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp#win',
              '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi @ElarbiMohamedAymen please can you modify and simplify your script simply to check if java 64 bit is present and if not, give the user a link for download from the official website of java? thank you

Comment: @NullPointerException done sir, now it will check if java is present otherwise it will promt a message to download it from server

Comment: thank you but something is not working. I added your code below my iss script, at the bottom. When i execute it it simply displays the dialog with "YOUR MESSAGE GOES HERE". I have java 64 bit jdk installed, and the script must check if a JRE of 64 bits is installed. Something is wrong

Comment: mmmm I disscovered that if you put "HKLM64" it checks for 64 bit version :)

Comment: Can this script be integrated in the inno setup step by step installer? instead of being launched before the setup?

Comment: @NullPointerException I never tried that before the integration part and I don't think so because the steps are already preprogramed. let me know if you've done it :)