# How to include 2 exe files in the same installer(in INNO setup)

Tags: java, inno-setup

So I made a program in JavaFX and I want to create an installer for it. But in order to run it I need JRE.

What can I do (in INNO SETUP) in order to have an installer that contains both applications:

- JRE
- My application

I want to install JRE automatically before or after installing my program.

I know that is something about `BeforeInstall` or `AfterInstall`.

This is the part of the code that I think that can help:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\cacaca.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; BeforeInstall: java ('{app}')

[Code]
procedure java();
begin
MsgBox('About to install MyProg.exe as ' + CurrentFileName + '.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Isn't that against JRE licence?

Comment: Anyway, see [How do I install a JRE from an Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24964393/850848)

Comment: Rather than installing a JRE with your installer, you should ship a private JRE with your program

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : I succeeded to install JRE with INNO. The problem is that after the instalation of JRE, the program is not continuing with the instalation of my application. Nothing happen like I want to install just JRE.

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath : Let's say that is not about java.It's about 2 random apps.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: the minimal code is up in the description:) .I need when i double click the installer generated by INNO, the installer to install 2 programs...2 executables that are existing in my computer...not just one...i want an installer to include 2 apps...to install them both one after another

Answer (score 0):

If you want more files installed, then include more [Files] (as needed). The Inno Setup Script Wizard (under the "file" menu as "new") should allow you to pick out as many files as you want, if you'd rather click through that than hand-write an installer.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\java.exe"; DestDir: "{app}/PrivateJava";
Source: "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\cacaca.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; BeforeInstall: java('{app}')
Source: "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\license.docx"; DestDir: "{app}";
Source: "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\*.dll"; DestDir: "{app}";

[Code]
procedure java();
begin
MsgBox('About to install MyProg.exe as ' + CurrentFileName + '.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```